# can mongodb have a collection inside the collection in JAVA in actual or logical way

Tags: java, mongodb-java

I searched my question in some other topics but they didn't answered or they are about document only.
I need to have collection of multimedia to share easily. for the same purpose ,I started with mongodb. put the file inside the collection is done , but im not sure even if its possible or not to put a collection inside another collection!
I think it should have a logical way to do that, for example make an ID for collection and put the ID inside the another collection. but as i said I am wondering how to do that and it is appreciated to let me know if you are familiar with mongodb + java driver.
if that is possible , it would be so nice to share with me a code example.
thank you

Edit:
I have a method that assigning a random key to the collection , and i will add this key as id to another collection. is that correct way ?

```js
    int mekey =  ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1000, 10000);   //create a random key
     String key = Integer.toString(mekey);      
    DBCollection collection = mongodb.getCollection(collectionName); 
        BasicDBObject index = new BasicDBObject(key,1);
        collection.createIndex(index);                         // set the key for collection
```

Comment: Collections are json representation of objects, since json allows multiple degrees of nesting objects, then mongo too

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. One solution would be to have an embedded array inside every element as an embedded collection. Another option would be (If you have an existing collection and you simply want to refer to it), is that whenever you want to query the embedded collection you could simply use the $lookup aggregation operator.

Comment: thank you for your answer, would you please give me a JAVA example in this case? since i am a bit confusing with the comman-prompt examples and converting them to java code. Best Regards

Comment: can I assign an index as ID to child-collection , then add that ID to father-collection ?

Comment: Can anyone please help me,

Comment: in this case should i ask new question or should wait for any help ?